# atan2 does not work with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, math-operators

Trying to plot the amplitude and argument of two sine waves in terms of their amplitudes and phases using `pgfplots`, An error appears while compiling the atan2 function (supported by `pgfmath`). Here is the example

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={$\sqrt{x^2+1-2x\cos(y)}$},
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
]
\addplot3[surf,domain=0:1,domain y=0:360,]
{sqrt(x^2+1-2*x*cos(y))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  title={$atan2(-\sin(y),x-cos(y)$},
 xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
]
\addplot3[surf,domain=0:1,domain y=0:360,]
{atan2(-sin(y),x-cos(y)};
  %{sqrt(x^2+1-2*x*cos(y))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The errors are:

```
    (line 31) Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) {atan2(-sin(y),x-cos(y)}
```

and

```
    (line 31) Missing = inserted for \ifdim. {atan2(-sin(y),x-cos(y)}
```

repeated several times

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It runs using {atan(-sin(y)/(x-cos(y)))}; I tried using ifthenelse to handle the quadrants but got errors about badly formed numbers.  I suspect the problem is that atan2 is not implemented in the fpu library.

Comment: Even {ifthenelse(x > .5, 1, 0)}; doesn't work.  Weird!  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false} doesn't help eiher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others already mentioned, the floating point unit (FPU) shipped with PGF currently has no implementation of atan2 (it should get one; this is a bug).

A workaround is to configure `pgfplots` that it should not use the FPU. This works for the image in question (but is, in general, not recommended since it limits both data range + precision).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  title={$atan2(-\sin(y),x-cos(y)$},
 xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
 use fpu=false
]
\addplot3[surf,domain=0:1,domain y=0:360,]
{atan2(-sin(y),x-cos(y))};
  %{sqrt(x^2+1-2*x*cos(y))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can fake it by falling back to PGF `atan2` function pretending to be a fpu implementation.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{myatan2}{2}{%
\begingroup%
  \pgfmathfloattofixed{#1}\edef\tempa{\pgfmathresult}%
  \pgfmathfloattofixed{#2}%
  \pgfkeys{pgf/fpu=false}%
  \pgfmathparse{atan2(\tempa,\pgfmathresult)}\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}%
  \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\pgfmathresult}%
  \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult%
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  title={$atan2(-\sin(y),x-cos(y)$},
 xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
]
\addplot3[surf,domain=0:1,domain y=0:360]
{myatan2({-sin(y)},{x-cos(y)})};
  %{sqrt(x^2+1-2*x*cos(y))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output is the same as John Kormylo's image.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got the quadrants right.

[image: atan2]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  title={$atan2(-\sin(y),x-cos(y))$},
 xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
]
\addplot3[surf,domain=0:1,domain y=0:360,]
{x == cos(y) ? ( -sin(y) > 0 ? 90: -90) :
 (x > cos(y) ? atan(-sin(y)/(x-cos(y))): 
 (-sin(y) > 0 ? 180+atan(-sin(y)/(x-cos(y))): atan(-sin(y)/(x-cos(y)))-180))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```