# Create a quiver plot with tikz & pgf using atan2()

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been trying to create a quiver plot like this:
[image: Lamb-Oseen vortex]

However doing the appropriate coordinate transformation this requires the atan2 function which does not seem to be supported by the current FPU shipped by PGF [seen here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203875/atan2-does-not-work-with-pgfplots#_=_).

However I could somehow not get pgf to accept the fixes offered in the link post mentioned before.

Here would be a MWE of the quiver plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-3:3, view={0}{90}]
\addplot3[blue, quiver={u={1}, v={(x-y)}, scale arrows=0.15}, -stealth,samples=20] {0};

%desired u and v: u={-sin(atan2(y,x))}, v={cos(atan2(y,x))}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As soon as I try to use atan2() I get error messages like:

> ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: `\addplot3[blue, quiver={u={-sin(atan2(y,x))}, v={cos(atan2(y,x))}, scale arrows=0.15}, -stealth,samples=20] {0};` does work for me.

Comment: do you have installed recent `pgfplot` and `tikz` packages?

Comment: @Zarko I just tried to update (via software-management on linux open-suse) and could not find a newer version of any of the tikz- or pgf-packages...

Comment: @Zarko, just tried - it's not a problem on Windows, where texmaker fetches its packages on its own...
Does one of you happen to know how to update packages on open-suse? Because the only way to install packages I have found so far is to get all of them in a bundle. Also I could not locate any pgf- oder tickz-packages in the file-system...

Comment: @GianAndreaMüller, sorry, i use `miktex` and only know how to update for it :-(. i believe that open-suse has similarly utility or procedure. or someone more familiar with it will help you.